# Как открывать новое окно при нажатом контроле в текущей вкладке?

Tags: javascript

На иконке, обороченной в `span` висит обработчик `onClick` с функцией, которая вызывает `window.open(url, '_blank', windowParams)`. При обычном клике открывается как надо - в текущей вкладке в новом окне, как модальное окно, но если открывать ctrl + click то открывает в новой вкладке. Как сделать так, чтобы оно открывалось всегда как модальное окно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение. Для того, чтобы всегда создавалось новое окно не смотря на нажатый ctrl - нужно обернуть вызов `window.open` в `setTimeout`. Что то вроде этого:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 window.open(url, target, params);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не проверял, но попробуй

```
var ctrlDown=false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKe) {
        ctrlDown=true;
    }
  }).addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
      if(event.ctrlKe){
          ctrlDown=false;
      }
  });

element.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(ctrlDown) {
        //открыть модальное окно
    }
})
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы даже при нажатом контроле открывалось окно как надо. В твоём варианте же будет вызываться только в случае, если контрол не нажат или его отпустили.